# call java script function from flash as3 android app to retrieve device id and serial no?

Tags: javascript, android, actionscript-3, flash

i want to call a java script function using flash as3 to get android device id and build serial no. I'm creating a android app. Is it possible to do that? or is there any way to get device id and build serial no using flash as3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Native Extension to get a unique ID for the device.

For example this one: http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#application

I don't understand where JS fits in all this though... to use a native extension you will have to compile in Adobe Air for Android, not flash Player.

Usually ANEs come compiled in an `.ane` file. You have to include that file in the Actionscript settings of your popject, and then use it from your code like any other AS3 package. Most likely the ANE developer has some example on how to use it in AS3.

Here's a a beginner tutorial on how ot use ANEs
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/using-ane-in-flash.html

Here's more info about ANEs
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to this kind of things. I did find a free native extension which can retrieve IMEI, MEID but don't really know how to use them. Link to the web site is https://github.com/goabonga/DeviceIDExtension. Need help to integrate it in my project and I'm using air for android.

Comment: anes work like normal libraries once there complied, import the class, create an instance and called the getID() function. See example [here](https://github.com/goabonga/DeviceIDExtension/blob/master/app/src/Application.as)

Comment: do i need to compile whole files and folder from https://github.com/goabonga/DeviceIDExtension ? And which software do i use ?